# Selenium Java (ATUReporter)- Getting java.lang.NullPointerException error while running the testng suite with ATUReporter

Tags: selenium, report

I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` error while running my project which has Testng framework configured with `ATUReporter`

Things I have done:

- Added the ATU jars in the project
- Added the `@Listeners({ ATUReportsListener.class, ConfigurationListener.class, MethodListener.class })` in my baseclass
- Added the line `System.setProperty("atu.reporter.config", "path\\ATU.properties");`
- Added this line to my testng file:

  ```
  <listeners>
      <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener" />
      <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ConfigurationListener" />
      <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.MethodListener" />
  </listeners>
  ```
- My ATU.properties file also is in the correct directory as mentioned in the Systemproperty line.

Please suggest !

**Base class Sample:**

```
@Listeners({ ATUReportsListener.class, ConfigurationListener.class, MethodListener.class })
public class test {
{
    System.setProperty("atu.reporter.config", "path\\ATU.properties");
}

@Test(priority=0)
public void login()
{
    OpenUrltest();
}
}
```

**Error StackTrace:**

> > java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException
> >             at atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener.onStart(Unknown Source)
> >             at org.testng.SuiteRunner.invokeListeners(SuiteRunner.java:210)
> >             at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
> >             at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
> >             at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
> >             at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1284)
> >             at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)
> >             at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
> >             at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
> >             at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
> >             at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
> >             at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
> >         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> >             at atu.testng.reports.utils.Directory.init(Unknown Source)
> >             at atu.testng.reports.utils.Directory.verifyRequiredFiles(Unknown Source)
> >             ... 12 more

Comment: can you share the stack trace of the error? and your Java class where you have registered the listeners.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener.onStart(Unknown Source)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.invokeListeners(SuiteRunner.java:210)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)

Comment: Modify your question, put your Base class and error stack trace in the question itself, don't post any info regarding question in your comments.

Comment: which version of ATUReporter are you using, can you paste the entire `BaseClass`. The above code isn't helping to dig down the issue.

Comment: @pArAs- Nevermind, i figured out the solution !! I was getting the error because i had created the ATU Reports directory manually for the output reports generation. After deleting this directory the error got wiped out clean, so i think ATU autocreates this directory on its run after configuration & 1st run. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: cool, either close the question or put an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error occured because the ATU Reports directory was manually created for the output reports generation. After deleting this directory the error got wiped out clean, so i think ATU autocreates this directory when you try to run the suite for the 1st time.